# Worker processes get ever released if recycling is turned off?

Tags: asp.net, iis, memory-leaks

In my web site, I turned off recycling on app pool recycling settings. I was wondering if worker process is still releasing its memory even though recycling is turned off? Since I turned off recycling, the memory usage by the web site is increasing without a limit. Does worker process create a new thread for each request? If so does each thread get killed after it serves the request?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, each request causes a new thread to be created or taken from the thread pool. The number of worker threads available per processor is governed by the `maxWorkerThreads` in the `processModel` section of the web.config. The range for this value is 5 to 100, with the default value being 20.

So the answer to your question is that each request gets its own thread and if none are available, then the request is queued up and processed once a thread is available. The thread is not necessarily killed when the request finishes, because it may return to the thread pool.

Comment: What about all the allocated objects? Do they get released when thread is done handling the request?